# Update Nunit Console Runner to version 3 on Sharpdevelop

Tags: nunit, sharpdevelop

I am having several problems running tests with new functionalities of Nunit Framework version 3.5

On SharpDevelop 5, I checked the version of Nunit Console installed on SharpDevelop 5 (`SharpDevelop\5.1\bin\Tools\NUnit`) and it is old (2.6.3.0). I think that by performing the upgrade to Nunit Console Version 3 I will not have any more problems.

Looking on `Nuget` I found [NUnit Console Runner Version 3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit.Console/3.5.0), but it is not being installed on SharpDevelop 5.

So, how can I upgrade the Nunit Console Runner?

Comment: A simple rule of open source projects is that you should send a pull request to fix that if nobody else works on it (I know you have posted an issue https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/issues/781).

Answer (score 3):

This was interesting - I learned something.

SharpDevelop comes with an nunit-console.exe 2.6.3 file which is **not** the same as our (nunit's) nunit-console.exe 2.6.3. All the other nunit assemblies appear to be the distributed NUnit binaries but this one is where they have added some new options and made some fixes. Consequently, I don't believe you can just drop in any release of NUnit you like and have it work.

In any case, even without the special executable build, you could not just drop in nunit3-console and the associated NUnit 3 assemblies. NUnit 3 is actually an entirely new program. It works differently from earlier releases internally and has a different set of options on the command-line.

Consequently, you are forced to stick with NUnit 2.6.x so long as you want to use the SharpDevelop runner. I'll look into possibly helping them with an upgrade (probably a new NUnit3 tool) if they are interested.

Comment: thank you for your answer (and thanks for NUnit!).

Well, I'm anxiously waiting to this integration, I believe this integration is very interesting and important to open source community.

Nunit 3 have great new features (TestContext, OneTimeSetUp and others) that do not works on SharpDevelop Nunit Runner.

I'm sorry to duplicate forum. Thank you again.